# Null column with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

**Background:**

I'm dealing with a legacy SQL Server 2000 database (yes, I AM changing it!). It has a column, which we can call name, which is nvarchar(100) and not null. I've verified this.

When I run this query:

```
select name
from mytable
where name is null
```

I get no results. However, when I run this query:

```
select name
from mytable
where name = ''
```

I get about 100 results. I wanted to find out a bit more about these blank values, since spaces would be legal in a non null column, so I ran this query:

```
select ASCII(substring(name, 1, 1))
from s
where name = ''
```

This returns "32" for about a third of the results, i.e. a space. For the other 2/3rds however, it is returning null.

**Question:**

1. How can there be null values in a column that has a not null definition?
2. Why are these null values not appearing in a "name is null" query?

Comment: You don't have `NULL` values, you said that yourself, right?.

Comment: I would guess that the character value '\0` is being interpreted as `NULL`.  I believe its official name is "NUL".

Comment: You need to understand that `ASCII(substring(name, 1, 1))` returning you `NULL`, doesn't mean that `name` is null

Comment: @Lamak: I don't have null values in the sense that "name is null" returns nothing.

Comment: And that means that there are no null values in it. As I said, `ASCII(substring(name, 1, 1))` is not the same as `name`

Comment: @Lamak: Going on what Gordon said, are these possibly character values then? I guess I'm confused as I don't get why they'd show as null.

Comment: And I still don't get it, they aren't being show as null, `ASCII(substring(name, 1, 1))` is giving you a null, right?

Comment: @Lamak: Yeah. So ASCII has converted it to a null value. But it isn't one to begin with. Is there anyway to delve in and find out what they ACTUALLY are?

Comment: `ASCII` isn't converting anything to a `NULL`, it's returning a `NULL`, that's completely different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have NULLs in the column `name`, you have verified that with your first query.

The `name = ''` condition matches both empty strings and strings of spaces.

When `name` is empty, `SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1)` is also empty, and so is the argument of `ASCII`. In this case `ASCII` returns NULL. When `name` is a string of spaces, the argument supplied to `ASCII` is a space, therefore the result is `32`, the ASCII code of the space character.